# how can i split table,text,images in pdf using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I have a PDF file.it contains texts,images,tables. I want to split text and store into separate folder,same thing for images and tables.

Comment: That is a very good question, but answer is hard to find and worth's a lot. This is not for StackOwerfow try freelancer service